# How Can I Fix This Error With Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm making a twitter like app with Parse, using swift 2 an Xcode 7.2

But I keep getting this error

> Cannot convert value of type '(PFUser!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFUserResultBlock?'

when I use the

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground
```

command.

My exact code is as follows:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!){
                (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                if ((user) != nil){

                    print("Login sucessful!")

            }
            else {

                print("Login failed")


                }
            }
        }))

    }
```

And when I try taking away the exclamation marks and/or replacing them with question marks I just have this error

> '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

I am new to swift and Xcode, so please don't treat me like an idiot, I am just new to swift, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closure should have type : `(PFUser?, NSError?) -> Void` not `(PFUser!, NSError!) -> Void`. Replace ! with ? in argument types in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 3.0, try replacing:

`(user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in`

with

`(user:PFUser?, error:Error?)->Void in`

First, if it works at all, I wouldn't recommend using `!`, because you'll crash if you normally access `user` or `error` and they're `nil` (one of them always is!).

Second, while Parse is written mostly in `obj-c`, which uses `NSError`, `NSError` appears to be imported as `Error` as of Swift 3!